# Matlab: how to manupulate expression

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I am currently having an equation that contains 4~5 variables, and I am unfamiliar with matlab. I want to see how a variable change with the other variable fixed (might assign them some value). Maying graphing them out will help.  I found it cumbersome to work in the main GUI in matlab, this is mainly after I type in my equation, I didn't know if the expression is what I want because of missing brackets, etc.

Recently I found mudpad, it is better because it will show you the expression in pretty form. I am wondering is there any other tool-box that is more suitable for my intention?

---

Update:

```
Ps=1;
Pr=1;
Pd=1;
g=0.25;
d1=1;
d2=1;
n=0.18;

Yr = @(x)(Ps)/(d1*((Pd*g^2)/d2 + (n*(x- 2))/(x- 1)));
Yr_=ezplot(Yr,0,1);
```

There is actually 4 more equations to plot and I am only posting one of them.

Comment: Hey, there. Please be more specific. Post the equation we are talking about here and how the output/behavior is supposed to look like. It would also be good if you included some code you have tried yourself.

Comment: If you want the value of the expression where you have a closed form solution, it is trivial. If you want to find solutions to a complex equation it requires more work. Cannot guess what your problem is.

Comment: @Floris, not complex equation

Comment: @timgeb, please see update I just posted